# elasticsearch : multiple set of synonyms fails with Invalid synonym rule

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 sets of synonyms, I get some error when I try to create an analyzer with both sets of synonyms. Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve

```
CASE:1
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "syn1": {
          "type": "synonym_graph",
          "synonyms": [
            "1, One",
            "2, Two",
            "3, Three"
          ]
        },
        "syn2": {
          "type": "synonym_graph",
          "synonyms": [
            "1, I",
            "2, II",
            "3, III"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "number_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "syn1",
            "syn2"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error I get is

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "failed to build synonyms"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "failed to build synonyms",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "parse_exception",
      "reason": "Invalid synonym rule at line 1",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "term: 1 analyzed to a token (1) with position increment != 1 (got: 0)"
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

BUT If i try to merge both synonyms into a single set it works

```
CASE:2
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "syn1": {
          "type": "synonym_graph",
          "synonyms": [
            "1, One",
            "2, Two",
            "3, Three",
            "1, I",
            "2, II",
            "3, III"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "number_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "syn1"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response

```
{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "shards_acknowledged" : true,
  "index" : "my_index"
}
```

why does case 1 fail and case 2 passes? 
Given that my application involves multiple sets of synonyms how do achieve case 1?

Comment: Looks like this is [open issue with stacked graphs](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/29426), adding `"lenient" = true` prevents the error but also prevents conflicting mappings to be ignored.

Comment: @nate yes seems like an open issue .. unfortunately lineant=true does not satisfy my applications use case